# react.js: change mui tab highlighted text color

Tags: reactjs

i have this simple tab panel:

```
 return (
      <Box  sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
          <Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {background:'#5F4730'}}} value={value} onChange={handleChange} >
            <Tab label="Chaträume" {...a11yProps(0)} />
            <Tab label="Offene Fälle" {...a11yProps(1)} />
            <Tab label="Geschlossene Fälle" {...a11yProps(2)} />
          </Tabs>
        </Box>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
          <ChatRoomList chatIDState={props.statePassDown} roomType={''}/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
          <ChatRoomList  chatIDState={props.statePassDown} roomType={'open'}/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
          TO DO
        </TabPanel>
      </Box>
    );
```

That is almost perfect. Except that the highlighted text color of the tab is turned to blue and looks like this:

[image]

How would I change the styling of the highlited color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the TabPanel component extend a tag?
If then you should do style={{color:'black'}}
Else you should do style to the TabPanel with color:'black'
I wish this could help you.